# Custom UI for button and edittext

Tags: android

I have been trying to design a button and a edittext in native android but unable to create the exact UI as shown in the picture. If anyone has any idea how can I create such UI please share your thoughts. In the image the first field should act as an input box and the second field should act as button.
[image]

Comment: You'll need some custom drawables, but that looks like just a Floating action button over two fields with rounded corners. How far have you gotten just trying to get the rounded corners of the rectangular piece? Worry about the circle later

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following given xmls will create the same UI you asked for. :)

1. create roundedbutton.xml resource file in drawable folder, given below

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <solid android:color="#eeC4C6C7" />
    <corners android:bottomRightRadius="30dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp"
    android:topRightRadius="30dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="30dp"/>
    </shape>
   ```
2. create roundededittext.xml resource file in drawable folder, given below

   ```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     android:shape="rectangle">
     <solid android:color="#eeCD3E22" />
     <corners android:bottomRightRadius="30dp"
    android:bottomLeftRadius="30dp"
    android:topRightRadius="30dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="30dp"/>
      </shape>
   ```

Create your main xml layout file. I created with your custom edit text, shown here:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="20dp">

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="@drawable/roundedbutton"
    android:elevation="10dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:text="t"
    />
<EditText
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="-30dp"
    android:elevation="2dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/roundededittext"/>

   </LinearLayout>
```

Hope it helps! Ask for any doubt.

Comment: Thanks. Your idea helped me a lot!